# Populating dropdown menu items (in JSP)

Tags: jsp, servlets, jpa, model-view-controller, ejb

Implementing simple blog app with JEE, EJB's, JPA, TomEE, MySQL, MVC - servlets + JSP.
This is page menu i have now:
http://jsfiddle.net/vvozar/tMz9A/

```
see menu look in jsfiddle link
```

How should i approach to populating menu items and subitems. I mean menu content should be created dynamically by reading values from database and creating menu subitems (see jsfiddle menu, concretely Category item and subitems) I don't know how to approach to realizing this. Probably some way in servlet, yes, just asking what is the practice. And how about then to have that menu filled when moving to other pages inside app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the servlet as controller and do something like this in your get method :

```
request.setAttribute("menus", service.getMenus());

getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/<your-page>.jsp")
                   .forward(request, response);
```

And in your jsp, something like :

```
<ul>
<%
    List<Menu> menus = (List<Menu>)request.getAttribute("menus");

    for (Menu menu : menus) {
%>
    <li><%= menu.getName() %></li>
<%
    }
%>
</ul>
```

If you need submenus, you can define a `List<SubMenu>` inside `Menu` and do another loop in the jsp.